# diff after EGit commit changing whole file, but ok in command line

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I don't understand why a commit in EGit is changing the whole file.

Yes, I'm on Windows, and I have core.autocrlf=true set globally in /etc/gitconfig.

Here's what I don't understand:

- the working copy starts off with DOS line endings both before and after edit
- When I edit the file in Eclipse and look at `git diff` through the command line, I only see the lines that I changed in the diff.
- If I `git add` and `git commit` through the command line as well, the `git diff HEAD^` shows only the lines I changed.
- When I do the commit through Eclipse/EGit instead, `git diff HEAD^` shows the entire file as changed, as if the Windows line endings were just added -- when my working copy *already* had DOS newlines before I touched it.

Any idea why the different behavior in EGit vs. git command line?  Where else could Eclipse/EGit be mangling line endings?